# Saving user settings in QML/JS

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I'm working on a small game and i'd like to know how can i write/read a user settings file in ubuntu touch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options, you can use a [LocalStorage](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/qmlmodule-qtquick-localstorage2-qtquick-localstorage-2.html) to create a local sqlite database to keep your settings in.  Or you can use the (still very alpha-stage) [U1DB](http://people.ubuntu.com/~mhall119/u1db-qt/u1db-qt-cheatsheet.html) component, which will still use a local sqlite database, but also allows you to sync your settings database between the user's different machines/devices.

Comment: the U1DB component seems to be the best option, thanks for the info.

Comment: This answer has an example of using LocalStorage to save user settings: http://askubuntu.com/questions/352157/how-to-use-a-sqlite-database-from-qml/355061#355061

Comment: The LocalStorage link is broken. I guess it moved to http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How-to_create_a_persistent_settings_database_in_Qt_Quick_(QML)

Comment: Also, I haven't found a way to edit settings in U1DB

Answer (score 0):

### LocalStorage example

`storage.js`

```
function getDatabase() {
     return LocalStorage.openDatabaseSync("appname", "0.1", "SettingsDatabase", 100);
}

function set(setting, value) {
   var db = getDatabase();
   var res = "";
   db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings(setting TEXT UNIQUE, value TEXT)');
        var rs = tx.executeSql('INSERT OR REPLACE INTO settings VALUES (?,?);', [setting,value]);
              if (rs.rowsAffected > 0) {
                res = "OK";
              } else {
                res = "Error";
              }
        }
  );
  return res;
}

function get(setting, default_value) {
   var db = getDatabase();
   var res="";
   try {
       db.transaction(function(tx) {
         var rs = tx.executeSql('SELECT value FROM settings WHERE setting=?;', [setting]);
         if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
              res = rs.rows.item(0).value;
         } else {
             res = default_value;
         }
      })
   } catch (err) {
       //console.log("Database " + err);
       res = default_value;
   };
  return res
}
```

#### QML imports

```
import QtQuick.LocalStorage 2.0
import "storage.js" as Settings
```

#### QML usage

```
Settings.get("setting_name",8)
Settings.set("setting_name", itemid.property)
```

I've used [this example](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How-to_create_a_persistent_settings_database_in_Qt_Quick_%28QML%29) but had to modify it.